# Implement OAuth in mvc 3. How to store user's details in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use OAUth in my existing mvc3 Application. I was able to authenticate the user using the below code

```
 [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
 //This action method is executed after the authentication from Facebook
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

    //Here i'm setting the Authentication cookie 
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(result.UserName, false);
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
}
```

The above code works fine . However my mvc3 application uses asp.net membership. My entire application uses Guid id's which come from the database  but i'm unable to figure out how to maintain the database for the OAuth Authenticated Users so that i can generate guid id.If i'm going in a wrong direction correct me. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you are using  **asp.net membership.**
Following is the way to register user

```
 MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(username, Password,Email);
```

Get user ID

```
newUser.ProviderUserKey
```

Comment: I'd like to distinguish between a normal registered user and a user who uses other third party websites like google,facebook .however both of them should have equal rights to access my website content. The above code which you have posted will create a user like the normal way.